# Use forEach on a list wrapper class in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, list

I replace a list with a wrapper class which allows to watch on changes of the list. Now, I can no longer iterate over the class with a `forEach` statement.

```
let numberList = new EventList<number>([1,2,3,4]);
numerList.forEach((element: number) => console.log(element));
```

I receive the following error:

> Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'EventList<number>'.

I expect that `EventList` implicitly has the `forEach` function because the class implements the `Iterable` interface.

This is the implementation of the `EventList<T>`:

```
export class EventList<T> implements Iterable<T>{
    private list: T[] = [];
    private changeListener: ((list: T[]) => void)[] = [];

    constructor(items: T[] = []) {
        this.list = items;
    }

    public push(element: T): void {
        this.list.push(element);
        this.emitChange();
    }

    public splice(index: number, deletCount?: number) {
        this.list.splice(index, deletCount);
        this.emitChange();
    }

    public onChange(callback: (list: T[]) => void) {
        this.changeListener.push(callback);
    }

    [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<T> {
        let currIndex = 0;
        const items = this.list;

        return {
            next(): IteratorResult<T> {
                if(currIndex < items.length) {
                    return { done: false, value: items[currIndex++] };
                } else {
                    return { done: true, value: null };
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private emitChange(): void {
        for (const listener of this.changeListener) {
            listener(this.list);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I expect that EventList implicitly has the forEach function because the class implements the Iterable interface" why? You are *implementing an interface*, not *extending a class*. An interface is just a schema, it doesn't implicitly have anything. Also, if that interface specified a `forEach` method (which your code doesn't implement) for the type your code wouldn't compile because you wouldn't be implementing the interface correctly

Comment: Ok. My formulation might be a bit confusion. I thought that after I implemented iterator from the interface, the `forEach` function can be derived from my implementation of the iterator.

Comment: Typescript compiles to Javascript and it doesn't really do codegen. Typescript types (including interfaces) have no runtime re-ification. Compiling just strips out the types (and fails if the types don't check). There are languages that can do what you are expecting (see `derive` in Rust or `deriving` in Haskell) but Typescript can't be one of them without changing its essential nature (again because it compiles to equivalent JS). Now if you *extend a class* like `Array` you get the implementations of the methods of that class, because that's a *Javascript* feature that just passes through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ForEach` is not implcitly implemented by `Iterable`.

The expected signature is:

```js
forEach(callback: (value: T, index: number, element: T[]) => void): void {
    this.list.forEach(callback);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Method forEach is not inherently available on the iterable object, I guess, and you should implement it.

```
forEach(callback: (item: T) => void) {
  for (const item of this) {
    callback(item);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to define forEach method in **EventList** class because it does not implement **Array** directly.
you have to append the below function:

```
public forEach(callback: (element: T) => void): void {
     this.list.forEach(callback);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Unfortunately, the signature of the `forEach` function is not correct

Comment: @Molitoris looks perfectly acceptable to me.